# Which preposition to use with "access"? "To" or "of"?

Tags: prepositions

I read a sentence which was:

Social differences among men and women were increased because of the difference in access of resources or property.

Personally, I don't think "of" should be used there. Am I right? I also wanted to ask if "of" can be used with it in some or other context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both ***to*** and ***of*** can appear after ***access***, but they have different meanings.

> I need **access to** your office to install the phone connection.

Here, *to* indicates what is to be accessed.

> We need to ensure **access of** the entire population to adequate healthcare.

Here, *of* indicated what will be doing or having the access. It's generally used when there's a *to* phrase as well, after the *of* phrase. You can all use *for* for the same purpose:

> The university takes **access for** women seriously.

I agree that your example should use *to*, at least in the absence of other context.

Comment: I came for _for_, so thanks for adding it in addition to what was asked :)